# Using bunny, how to set x-max-length when connecting to existing queue

Tags: rabbitmq, bunny

I've got the following ruby function to connect to an existing rabbit queue with a `max_length` value of 10000

```
  def self.send(settings, event_str)
    conn = Bunny.new(
        hostname: settings['host'],
        username: settings['user'],
        password: settings['password'],
        virtual_host: settings['virtual_host']
    )
    conn.start
    ch = conn.create_channel
    q = ch.queue(
        settings['queue'],
        durable: true,
        auto_delete: false,
        x_max_length: 10000
    )
    ch.default_exchange.publish(event_str, :routing_key => q.name)
  end
```

When invoked, this error is returned:

```
PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-max-length' for queue 'event_queue' in vhost '/sensu': received none but current is the value '100000' of type 'signedint'
```

Bunny version: 2.0.1
Ruby version: 2.3.1

I've experimented with various params to`ch.queue` but can't find a way to set a value for max queue length.

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the trick is to set an `arguments` hash as a param  to `ch.queue`

```
    q = ch.queue(
        settings['queue'],
        durable: true,
        auto_delete: false,
        :arguments => { 'x-max-length' => settings['queue_length'].to_i }
    )
```